# Convert a project.json to a csproj without using Visual Studio

Tags: dotnet-cli, .net-core

As of preview3 `dotnet new` produces a csproj, and both `dotnet restore` and `dotnet build` fail against a project.json and/or an xproj.

For instance, running `dotnet restore` against a directory that has both a project.json and an xproj gives this error.

> ...xproj(7,3): error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\1.0.0-preview3-004056\Extensions\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\DotNet\Microsoft.DotNet.Props" was not found. Confirm that the path in the  declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.

Further, running it against a directory that has only a project.json gives this error.

> MSBUILD : error MSB1003: Specify a project or solution file. The current working directory does not contain a project or solution file.

Without using Visual Studio, how can we convert an existing project.json and/or xproj to a csproj?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is a [`dotnet migrate` command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/preview3/tools/dotnet-migrate).

> The dotnet migrate command will migrate a valid Preview 2 project.json based project to a valid Preview 3 csproj project.

We can find detailed help on this command by running `dotnet migrate -h` (even though `dotnet -h` does not list the command).

Comment: + remove it if you have a global.json in your solution - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/migration/#dotnet-migrate

Comment: "running" it where?

Comment: @SeanKendle Run the command from your shell (e.g. bash, cmd, PowerShell) in the directory that contains the `project.json` file.

Comment: Ah, ok thanks!  There are a few command line tools in VS, and I tried in there to no good end, obviously.